# require is not defined using polyfill to fixPromise is not defined on IE 11

Tags: javascript, babel-polyfill

I'm getting the error message `Promise is not defined` on Internet Explorer 11, I've installed `babel-polyfill` with npm in order to fix it, and I  set on the top  op the js(simple js file,not angular or any other framework) file included on the viw this code

```
require("@babel/polyfill");
```

but I get `require is not defined`.How I have to include polyfill?

Comment: Show your `.babelrc` file. Also, to be able to use `require` or ES6's `import` you will need a bundler like webpack, parcel.js or rollup. To use the polyfills without a bundler, you need to include this script in your HTML before your own JS:

Comment: I don't have, never used polyfill.  total noob

Answer (score 3):

To be able to use `require` or ES6's `import` you will need a bundler like webpack, parcel.js or rollup.

To use the polyfills without a bundler, you need to include this script in your HTML **before** your own JS:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.0.0/polyfill.min.js
```

So add a `script` tag:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.0.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

In that case of course you remove that line `require("@babel/polyfill");` from your own JS.

If you are already transpiling with babel, you can also use [this plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd) to tranform the `import '@babel/polyfill'` syntax to something a browser will understand.

Comment: Might also add that there are babel plugins that will transform modules to e.g. UMD.

Comment: I've included polyfill this way but I still get the `Promise is not defined` error

Comment: @afsdi3 make sure it comes before any script tags with your code as connexo mentioned.

Comment: @afsdi3 check the network tab in devtools and make sure it's actually being loaded.